# Howto set Return-Path in Laravel 9 (Symfony Mailer)

Tags: php, laravel-9, symfony-mailer

If I just add the header in the mailable:

```
public function headers()
{
    return new Headers(
        text: [
            'Return-Path' => config('mail.from.address'),
        ],
    );
}
```

I get an error:

> The "Return-Path" header must be an instance of
> "Symfony\Component\Mime\Header\PathHeader" (got
> "Symfony\Component\Mime\Header\UnstructuredHeader").

Answer (score 2):

Only solution I found was with ["using" in Envelope](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mail#customizing-the-symfony-message):

```
public function envelope()
{
    return new Envelope(
        using: [
            function (Email $message) {
                $message->getHeaders()->addHeader('Return-Path', config('mail.from.address'));
            },
        ]
    );
}
```

That works for me.

I also tried to add a name:

```
use Symfony\Component\Mime\Address as SymfonyAddress;
$message->getHeaders()->addHeader('Return-Path', new SymfonyAddress(config('mail.from.address'), config('mail.from.name')));
```

But that creates an invalid result:

```
Return-Path: <"Some Name" <no-reply@someaddress.com>>
```

I guess name is not supported here?

Comment: I believe that's correct: names are not supported in the return-path. The intention for return-path is that it is a machine readable email address to send bounce, and other automated notifications to, and shouldn't be visible to users. 

The reply-to address will be the user-visible variant. Often these two values are the same email address, but being able to set the return path separately is important.

https://mxtoolbox.com/dmarc/spf/setup/spf-return-path

Thanks for your answer! It really helped me get things configured to prevent bounced mail notifications from flooding our inbox!